# Positioning form input in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am building a login page with react, and here is what I have got

```
class Landing extends Component {
  state = {
    box: {
      width: "300px",
      height: "100px",
      margin: "0 auto",
      border: "1px solid blue",
      textAlign: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      lineHeight: "90px",
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },

    landingBody: {
      backgroundColor: "#ccffff",
      height: `100vh`,
      width: `100vw`,
      display: `flex`,
      alignItems: `center`,
      justifyItems: `center`,
    },
  };

  getForm() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="50" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="pin">PIN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" maxlength="4" size="4" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </form>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.landingBody}>
        <div style={this.state.box}>{this.getForm()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

I want the box to be in the center of the page, and the username and pin textboxes well inside the box. But the textboxes overflows way out of the containing box. Also, the shape is a bit wierd.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question title, something like "Positioning form input with React". Your question is not related to login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove the height prop of the box, `flexbox` landingbody then can holding the box in center position.

```
box: {
      width: "300px",
      margin: "0 auto",
      border: "1px solid blue",
      textAlign: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      lineHeight: "90px",
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
```

Second, the size of your pin textbox is 50, maybe this prop makes the input so long to overflow the container, you can remove it, restyle it's width.

```
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
```

Any question?

Answer (score 1):

modify input width id `fname` like below:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="50" style={{width: '100%',height: '5px'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to decrease the height?

Comment: Height of what?

Comment: Obviously, you should to add height style to this input

Answer (score 1):

The whole CSS style object shouldn't be in `state` as you aren't probably changing all the values.

The main reason your elements are overflowing is: `size="50"` and `lineHeight: "90px"`. You should use width and height instead.

Also I recommend using a CSS framework to make it look a bit nicer.
Here, I quickly made an example login page for you using Bulma https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-gould-ill5z